# Function undefined - External JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I want to create an organized js lib. for my application.

I am moving to external js files.

However, when I try to call my function from my page it shows as undefined.

What am I missing here? Why am I getting undefined error yet am able to log to console from the undefined function?

My external js look something like:

```
var fmp = (function () {

    var _fmp = {};

    ////////////////////
    //layout
    ////////////////////
    _fmp.layout = {
        setLayoutHeight : function (dom, height) {
            console.log(dom, height);
        }
    };



    ////////////////////
    //templates
    ////////////////////
     _fmp.templates = { };

    //Kendo Grid Client Template for Customer Results/List in Card View format
    _fmp.templates.CustomerListCardView = function (data) {
        return '<div class="pure-g">' +
            '<div class="pure-u-8-24"></div>' +
            '<div class="pure-u-16-24">' + data.CustomerId + '</div>' +
            '</div >';
    };


     ////////////////////
    //page specific
    ////////////////////
    _fmp.page = {};

    //Map page
    _fmp.page.Map = {};
    _fmp.page.Map.InitMap = function (dom,height) {
        var map;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(dom), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });
        console.log(map);
        $("#"+dom).height(height);
    };

    return _fmp;
})();
```

This outputs in console

```
#app-splitter,section.panel 957.432 

ReferenceError: setLayoutHeight is not defined
```

I call this from html as:

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            //named functions only

            fmp.layout.setLayoutHeight("#app-splitter,section.panel",957.432);
        });
</script>
```

Document Layout looks like:

```
@using FMPWeb.Classes;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - TelerikAspNetCoreApp1</title>
    <environment names="dev,local,qa">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/puregrids.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment names="test,prod">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/puregrids.css" />
    </environment>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Header", (int)UiConstants.ComponentHeader.HeaderAuthenticated)
    <application>
        @RenderBody()
    </application>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Window", (int)UiConstants.ComponentWindow.WindowMasterNav)
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @*<link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/styles/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    @*<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/jszip.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.3.1017/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

```
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: true)
    @Html.Kendo().DeferredScripts()

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well the code as posted gets a syntax error.

Comment: Oops, typo. Revised.

Comment: Wouldn't wrapping it in an IIFE mean `fmp` is undefined?

Comment: Sorry, that's another typo.  I should have just copied and pasted.  Please check agin.

Comment: I am asking, why when calling fmp.layout.setLayoutHeight(x,y) I am getting undefined error? When the function appears to be called since it is logging to the console.

Comment: @Liam, what is missing here?  I've added my HTML layout.  What else do you need?

Comment: `fmp.js` is the very last script included on the page.  As such that variable will not be defined until it is included

Comment: @Tamplar,  does wrapping my call to the fmp function in a doc.ready not solve that?

Comment: That's true.  If the variable was not defined, then it should be erroring whey you try to access the `.layout`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_fmp` will only exist within the scope of your anonymous function. As it stands, `fmp` doesn't actually return anything, so when you define `fmp` here, you're just running a function that creates a local-scope variable, sets its layout property, and then... does nothing with it. It will likely just be garbage collected away. If you want access to `_fmp`, you must return it from that function once you've defined all its properties.

Comment: Please see comments.  That was a copie/paste typo.  I do return _fmp.

Comment: Assuming you're returning it as you say, and that you're including your external file before trying to use it, I can see nothing wrong. Can you show use the HTML of your page?

Comment: I've updated the question to show the html layout and inclusion of script files.

Comment: I don't know much about how ASP.net does its templates, but I do notice you're including `fmp.js` all the way at the bottom of your page. That means it'll load last, after everything else, so I'm guessing you're probably trying to access `fmp` before it's even been loaded.

Comment: I am doing that on purpose, as some of the components in this file are dependent on the initialization of 3rd party widgets/controls.   I thought by including at the end and then wrapping it in a doc.ready wrapper would prevent any issues.   Other functions/objects are accessible in this file. It is specially the setting layout height.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I did overlook that `$`. So what is the value of `fmp.layout` if you log it to the console?

Comment: Object { setLayoutHeight: setLayoutHeight()}

Comment: So when you log `fmp.layout`, you get that, but if you try to call `fmp.layout.setLayoutHeight()` in the same place, it says it's undefined? That doesn't make a lot of sense...